# How to execute cucumber feature using tags from maven?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

How to execute cucumber from maven with tags?

what I have tried is

1. mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@TestTag"
2. mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@TestTag'"

my pom.xml has for  testng.xml files, ( *is there is a way to avoid executing  scripts from.xml files and directly with a tag name of a scenario or feature file ?* )

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

*Am using cucumber.io 7.0.0*

Comment: I am not sure how you use testng.xml. Normally cucumber run does not require that file.

Comment: Can you help me  this,  how to execute scripts without xml from maven? ( like should I remove the surefire configs in pom.xml )

Answer (score 0):

please use the following command, we should not use single quote

```
mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @temp"
```

for multiple,

```
mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @ISEAdmin-View/Modify,@ISEAdmin-ReadOnly"
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to modify anything in pom.xml? ,  am still struck in the same step

Comment: Not required. This is running fine for me.